# How to Cache Webservice request in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

I want to cache the Webservice request, when there is no network and hit again the same request asynchronously when there is network. (It should work also when app is in background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use priority queue( if there is priority to the requests), detect whenever network is failing(you can use Reachability for determine connectivity)

[Apple Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

When the connection status changes just executed the cashed request from the queue.
You could optionally write this data to Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [SQLite](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/) for every Caching purposes.